# XML namespace deserialization in .Net Core 6

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to deserialize the following in a .Net Core 6 Web API. (Note also the xmlns="" at the end of the .)

```
<message xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" user="xxx" password="yyy" type="zzz" from="aaa" xmlns="">
<HeaderInfo>
    <Vendor>vendor</Vendor>
    <MessageID>1078</MessageID>
    <Action>new</Action>
    <SiteName>site</SiteName>
```

My program.cs looks like this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
```

And my class looks like this:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "message", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
public class XmlDto
{
    [XmlAttribute("user")]
    public string? User { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("password")]
    public string? Password { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string? Type { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("from")]
    public string? From { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "HeaderInfo")]
    public HeaderInfo HeaderInfo { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Header")]
    public Header Header { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(DataType = "string")]
    public string? Body { get; set; }
}
```

What do I need to do to successfully deserialize this? I realize that I only have the one Namespace in the XmlRoot right now, but removing the other 2 xmlns's doesn't seem to make a difference. I'm currently receiving "An error occurred while deserializing input data." when I send the packet.

The 2nd question is do I even care? I don't believe that the sending application ever specifies anything using either of the "named" namespaces so there shouldn't ever be any ambiguity in interpreting the input.

Thanks

Comment: You don't need a namespace, at least not the xsi or xsd one. I would expect no namespace would work.

Comment: Pls post your xml . We need to know what you are talking about if you want some help.

Answer (score 0):

this works ok for me

```
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(message));
    using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        message result = (message)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class message
{
    public messageHeaderInfo HeaderInfo { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string user { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string password { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string type { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string from { get; set; }
}


[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class messageHeaderInfo
{
    public string Vendor { get; set; }
    public ushort MessageID { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string SiteName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]` seems unnecessary, it's all the defaults. Also `Attribute` at the end of each attribute name can be omitted.